Filling a triangular trough from a large aperture
A triangular trough of width W, length L, and vertical depth D fills with water from an aperture of width w and height h. The supply height of water exactly matches the aperture.
Water flows at a constant rate Q according to Torricelli's Law.
In terms of w and h, what is $y$ the depth of the water in the trough at a given time?
Here's what I've got:

$Q = \frac{2}{3} w h^\frac{3}{2} \sqrt{2g}$ by integrating vertically, according to an AI assistant but I don't think the dimensional analysis checks out
partly filled, the depth is $y$ with surface width $x=\frac{W}{D}y$
water volume is $V(t) = Lxy = \frac{LW}{2D}y^2 = Q t$
$y = \sqrt{\frac{2QDt}{LW}}$

I have a hunch this is wrong. Can you help me finish please?


Why the AI assistance?

There seems to be some missing data here. How far, $H$, does water extend above the aperture? You need this to apply Torricelli's law, in which case the rate law you have is almost correct. It would be $\frac{2}{3}w((h+H)^{3/2}-H^{3/2})\sqrt{2g}$. The reason why it looked like the dimensional analysis was wrong was because you inputted the Newtonian gravitational constant ($\text{m}^3\cdot\text{kg}^{-1}\cdot\text{s}^{-1}$), rather than the gravitational acceleration ($\text{m}\cdot\text{s}^{-2}$).

The incoming water exactly fills the aperture.

So if $H=0$ then the formula is correct? Dimensions of $Q$ would then be $L.L^\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{L.T^{-2}}=L^{1+\frac{3}{2}+\frac{-1}{2}}T^{-1}=L^2.T^{-1}$ but it should be $L^3.T^{-1}$, right?

@spraff You subtracted $\frac{1}{2}$ from the exponent of $L$ when you should have added. Correcting that gives the $L^3$ term you need.

I guess there should be  "$V(t)=Lxy/2$" instead of "$V(t)=LXy$".
